# Swift custom UITableViewController: switch statement case label section enum

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, enums, switch-statement

To make my code more readable & maintainable, what's the best way to use labels instead of hardcoded `Int`s for case labels in a switch statement with a control expression of type `Int`?

E.g., inside my `SettingsTableViewController`, I tried

```
enum Section : Int {
    case Phone
    case LogOut
    case DeleteAccount
}
```

and in `– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
switch indexPath.section {
case .Phone:
    // Push EditPhoneViewController
case .LogOut:
    // Log out
case .DeleteAccount:
    // Present action-sheet confirmation
}
```

but got the compile error

```
Enum case pattern cannot match values of the non-enum type 'Int'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the switch you can't simply use `indexPath.section` as that is not the same type as your enum.

Use `switch Section(rawValue: indexPath.section)!`

Comment: it would be a safer to do `if let section = Section(rawValue: indexPath.section) { switch section { } }` instead of using ! and crashing if you get an unexpected section number.